# Android Video/Image/Audio upload from gallery to java server using jsp/servlet

Tags: android, jsp

I am trying to upload items from gallery especially video/audio into Java server using servlet/jsp.

I need the code in jsp or servlet to upload video,audio and image from android gallery.

Comment: Show Your maybe experimetal code,

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Comment: http://www.mayanklangalia.blogspot.in/2014/04/how-to-upload-image-audio-and-video-on.html